# 'Attempt to modify property of non-object' warning

Tags: functions

** **This question is outdated!** **

I use the bellow function to disable a plugin update. It works, because I use an old version of this plugin and it does not show me that a newer version exists, but, however, I get a warning on line 2: *Attempt to modify property of non-object*. How to fix this?

```
function my_filter_plugin_updates( $value ) {
   unset( $value->response['duplicator/duplicator.php'] ); //Duplicator
   return $value;
}

add_filter( 'site_transient_update_plugins', 'my_filter_plugin_updates' );
```

**UPDATE**

I am not a PHP coder, so I do not know if what I did is correct, but this works - no errors, no warnings, no plugin update:

```
// Disable plugin update
function my_filter_plugin_updates() {
   $value = new StdClass;
   unset( $value->response['duplicator/duplicator.php'] ); //Duplicator
   return $value;
}

add_filter( 'site_transient_update_plugins', 'my_filter_plugin_updates' );
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can. The code you have looks to be taken from http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25358/turn-off-auto-update-for-single-plugin - and had the same problem there. There are also other solutions on that post.

Comment: @vancoder Thank you! You are right, but I like this solution and I hope it can be improved.

Comment: It looks like you're disabling all plugin updates this way, since `$value` is always a new empty object?

Answer (score 7):

Some simple php, check if it's set before trying to unset it.

```
function my_filter_plugin_updates( $value ) {
   if( isset( $value->response['duplicator/duplicator.php'] ) )
       unset( $value->response['duplicator/duplicator.php'] ); //Duplicator

   return $value;
}
add_filter( 'site_transient_update_plugins', 'my_filter_plugin_updates' );
```

Comment: Thank you! I will test your improved code, but I discovered another way (see my update). I am not a PHP coder, so I do not know if what I did is correct, but this works - no errors, no warnings, no plugin update.

Answer (score 1):

This could be late but assigning a new instance of an object, you are overwritten the proper value of `$value`