# How to remove 'View Details' page & updates from third-party plugin?

Tags: plugins

I'm making a site for a friend and decided to use a plug-in I found in the wordpress repository, since I am new to wordpress. However, I ended up changing a significant amount of the code to make it fit my needs. Because the original plugin was in the repository, it still links to the plugin page with a 'View Details' link and presumably will receive updates from the original author. How do I unlink this? I am worried that the person I'm making this website for will decide to click update, therefore undoing all my careful work.

Comment: Change the plugin name to something unique. If I can remember correctly, this is all that is needed. Just a note though, adhere to any special licence requirements there may be from the original author. Don't make code yours if you did nkot write it, always leave some credit to the author :-)

Comment: Duplicate question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25358/turn-off-auto-update-for-single-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Disable All WordPress Updates Plugin can be useful for your requirement, this is the link for that plugin [Disable All Updates](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-wordpress-updates/screenshots/). And there are a few tips to disable all updates section in admin backend. [disable plugin tips](http://www.wpoptimus.com/626/7-ways-disable-update-wordpress-notifications/) *This is the code to disable update notification*

```
remove_action('load-update-core.php','wp_update_plugins');
add_filter('pre_site_transient_update_plugins','__return_null');
```

Comment: To be honest, not a really good idea to disble updates just because of one plugin.

Comment: Please don't do this to remove one plugins View Details